# Detecting graphics driver issues in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-interface, graphics

I have a C# WPF application that was running and encountered an issue with the graphics driver. The error was "Display driver has stopped responding and recovered".

Is there a way to detect this error within the WPF application?

Comment: This is a relevant article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2665946/display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-recovered-error-in-windows-7

Comment: All of those things are manual actions to do after this has occurred. I want to be able to detect this within the application and choose an action accordingly (e.g. Log an error, shutdown)

Comment: There is not enough information for us to help you.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to handle *environmental* errors, even most common one (e.g. missing/corrupted framework), that would be a responsibility of the user to create suitable environment. All your software has to do is to crash. What exactly you are trying to achieve (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295))?

Comment: Usually there will be dispatcher exception https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexception?view=netcore-3.1 This should be raised on any exception that happens on Dispatcher and also in case of Rendering errors. Usually you wont be able to do much, based my experience in most case you will have rendering errors if the GPU is faulty, in some cases updated VGA driver might help.

Comment: @Sinatr What I am trying to do here is detect it and crash. This happened recently in my WPF application and the application kept running. I don't want that. I want to know when this happens and bring the application down.

Comment: Shouldn't it already crash? I guess it's just freeze. Then you can run 2 applications: one will monitor and ping another via IPC. It should be possible then to report/log a problem, but you can also try to shutdown frozen application.

Comment: No, it doesn't crash. The TDR functionality in Windows tries to detect and recover the driver but sometimes the application freezes or keeps going but just shows a blank screen. What I would like to do is detect when this is happening and explicitly bring the application down.

Comment: For me the problem is the same. When I see the error message in Application event log: "Display driver igfx stopped responding and has successfully recovered.", all the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke stucked. Any other thread still alive. The problem is when you don't know that the Dispatcher is freezed, the other threads make huge memory consumption, so after some minute the entire OP is crash. :( Any suggestion?